# Is there a way to disable xdebug's var_dump temporarily?

Tags: zend-framework, xdebug, zend-log

I want to use Zend_Debug::dump, to keep some variables in the log,
but since I have xdebug installed, and xdebug replaces php's var_dump, my values in log are html values produced by xdebug.

I was wondering if there is a way in php to disable this feature, and enabled it again, so that I could put them above and below this line:

```
    $Message = Zend_Debug::dump($objects, null, false);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Internally `Zend_Debug` uses var_dump, and AFAIK you can't turn off XDebug's var_dump overloading in runtime.

You can do two thing to get your output without html tags.

1. Disable html_errors by  `ini_set('html_errors', 0)` before dump.
2. Instead of using Zend_Debug, use `$Message = print_r($objects, true)` - notice second parameter.

Comment: Just a FYI comment, my favorite dump code : `die('<pre>' . var_export($var, true));`

Answer (score 28):

I had to add `xdebug.overload_var_dump=off` to `php.ini` to *disable* xdebug's overloading the `var_dump()` function, permanently for me.